# R: How can I subtract the diagonal matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, algebra

I am working with a Variance and covariance matrix. So, I need to make some transformation of it, now my idea is that given a determinated matrix:

```
SOFM<-matrix (data=1:5, nrow=4, ncol=4)

1 5 4 3
2 1 5 4 
3 2 1 5
4 3 2 1
```

I need to substract the diagonal matrix from my original matrix. i am using this code

```
SOFM-diag(diag(SOFM))
```

The result would  be:

```
0 5 4 3
2 0 5 4 
3 2 0 5
4 3 2 0
```

But, it does not function.

Comment: `diag(SOFM) <- 0`

Comment: Your original code is working fine. Eventually you want `SOFM <- SOFM-diag(diag(SOFM))`

Comment: @jogo why not post as answer?

Comment: @sindri_baldur it is too basic.